# how to populate android list view with data fetched from Mysql databse?

Tags: android, mysql

I am making one app in which i have to fetch selected data from the Mysql database. 
This is what I have done so far.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.clientmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
    Button b;
     EditText et;
   HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userid);
   /* pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);*/

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Validating user...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

void login(){
    try{

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.114/cm/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
       // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
               // tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Projects.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Projects.java

```
package com.clientmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
      import android.widget.ListAdapter;
      import android.widget.ListView;
      import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
      import android.widget.TextView;

public class Projects extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String urlallproducts = "http://192.168.0.114/cm/getallprojects.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PROJECTS = "projects";
private static final String TAG_USERID = "userid";
private static final String TAG_CAR_REG_NO = "car reg no";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = " address";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    projectsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProjects().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String userid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.uid)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
           Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),listitem.class);
            startActivity(in);
            // sending pid to next activity
           // in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
           // startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

   /* // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        }

     }
 */
    /**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProjects extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Projects.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading projects. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(urlallproducts, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Projects: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROJECTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                    String project = c.getString(TAG_PROJECTS);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_USERID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_PROJECTS, project);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    projectsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
               // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        //NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
               // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               // startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Projects.this, projectsList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_USERID,
                        TAG_ADDRESS},new int[] { R.id.uid, R.id.add });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

getallprojects.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

  // array for JSON response
   $response = array();


  // include db connect class
 require_once ('dbconnect.php');

 // connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM tbl_user ") or die(mysql_error());

  // check for empty result
   if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["projects"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $project = array();
    $project["userid"] = $row["userid"];
    $project["project"] = $row["project"];
    $project["car reg no"] = $row["car reg no"];
    $project["address"] = $row["address"];


    // push single project into final response array
    array_push($response["projects"], $project);
}
// success
    $response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
 } else {
   // no products found
   $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "No projects found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
```

?>

My app is not showing the data fetched in the list view.
No ERRORS in the log cat.

Please guide.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: From your classes it's seems you have a list of records, Now just create a adapter class extending ArrayAdapter<listObject Type> and override the adapter methods. In your Activity class set this adapter class to the listview and call notifydatasetchanged of this adapter when ever your binding record list get refreshed. Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: you don't need `RunOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute` , did you check `projectsList` value?